# What is the smoke made by the fogging machine? Is it harmful to humans?

Tags: chemistry

What is the principle of a fogging machine ?
on what process a fogging machine depends ? 
distillation or vapourization ?
what is the harmful effect of fogging machine ?

Comment: Have you done any research? a google search should give you the answers.

Comment: First result for "fog machine liquid ingredients" https://looksolutionsusa.com/are-fog-machines-safe/

Comment: Normally you would prefer to use a hazor instead of a fog machine if you can.